# Is there a specific preferred order of operation of signals?

Tags: signal, signal-processing

Basic Signal Operations Performed on Dependent Variables--
The periodicity of the signal is varied by modifying the horizontal axis values, while the amplitude or the strength remains constant. These are:-

Time scaling of signals

Reflection of signals

Time-shifting of signals.

***Is there a specific preffered order in which we should operate?***

Comment: Things you do to signals depend on the things you want to achieve.

Comment: Engineering is always about doing things to achieve goals! It's never "we always do this", it's always "in order to achieve this, we do A, and not B, because A leads to the desired result. In other situations, we use B"; I'm a bit confused on how you came to the conclusion things have a "preferred" order. Engineering is *deriving the right procedure to use from the things we need to achieve*. This applies to multiple of your questions!

Comment: @MarcusMüller What they probably meant is that if we have a signal like y1 = sin(2t - pi), which can be obtained by shifting and scaling/shrinking y2 = sin(t), do we perform the shifting first, or the scaling?

Comment: @Anurag this question is > 2 years old. If you want to ask a new, precise question, please do so.

Comment: I know how old this question is, but we both know that old questions can become active again anytime in the future. Also, I'm not sure whether a new question is really needed here, because this question can easily be interpreted in the way that I stated. Whether you want to interpret it that way and then answer it is your choice, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no preferred order of operations in signal analysis.

But you should note that the order of operations performed on a signal matters. You can think of these operations like matrices. Much like a AxB != BxA (generally), performing operation A, then operation B on a signal results in a (usually) different signal.

Take for example:

[image: Reflection at t = 0, then shift to the left by 1]
(Reflection at t = 0, then shift to the left by 1)

vs

[image: ![e^(at) > e^(at + 1) > e(-(at + 1)) = e(-at - 1)]] (Shift to the left by 1, then reflection at t = 0)